# How to fix Curl SSL CA Cert error

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate, xero-api

I implemented the Xero-API using [this library](https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroOAuth-PHP), having implemented it, it worked fine on localhost, then i uploaded to my server then i get this error

```
Curl error: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

Comment: check that `curl` installed on your server or not?

Comment: @urfusion I think curl is installed, because of "curl error". Is the CA cert installed on server?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the certs do exist in the path and php has the ability to access the server. Try restart apache first, it might be something simple, if not try regenerate the cert, it might have gotten corrupt somehow.